# Creating and configuring an Ubuntu .vdi image

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, vdi

I have taken some courses that provide a .vdi file for Virtual Box so that students don't have to configure their own machines. How can I create one of these images with Ubuntu on it? What is the best way to configure it? Should I use some tool like Vagrant, Chef, or Puppet (I haven't used any of these so I don't know exactly what they are for)?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of internet pages that offer different Ubuntu images in different configurations. The two top google hits are:

1. [VirtualBox Images](http://virtualboximages.com/VirtualBox+Ubuntu+Client+VDIs)
2. [VirtualBoxes](http://virtualboxes.org/)

But there are lots more. Note that you can also use vmdk (VMWare) images and import them to VirtualBox. [VMPlanet](http://vmplanet.net/) is the leading site for VMWare images.

Comment: How do you create them from scratch?  #1 seems a little shady.

Comment: The easier way is to install Ubuntu in VBox, install the needed packages and share the VDI.